# How to create Excel files based on dynamic results of a MS Access Query

Tags: ms-access

In MS Access, I have a query that shows several **Errors** in each **Zone**. I need to create a summary in Excel for each **Zone**, which will change each week. I created a query that will determine which zones are present for that weeks report.

```
Zone
Zone 1
Zone 3
Zone 4
Zone 5
```

I would need to create the following files: Zone1.xlsm, Zone3.xlsm, Zone4.xlsm, Zone5.xlsm

I am a complete novice, so any advice would help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb214134%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Very roughly:

```
''The query with unique zones
Set rs = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset("select zones from zonequery")

Do While Not rs.EOF
   ''The sql to get the data
   ssql="SELECT * FROM Whereever Where Zone='" & rs!Zone & "'"

   ''An existing query called MyZoneOutputQuery
   CurrentDB.QueryDefs("MyZoneOutputQuery").sql=ssql

   DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
      "MyZoneOutputQuery", "z:\docs\" & rs!Zone & ".xlsm", True
   rs.Movenext
Loop
```